# How are these nested vectors connected?

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I've written a piece of code, which creates a vector 'scoreboard' that contains 3 seperate vectors of size 3, all containing the symbol ? at all indices 0-2. When i now execute a 'vector-set!' on the first vector of scoreboard, to change its first element to a 'X, vectors 2 and 3 will change too. How does this occur?

```
(define scoreboard (make-vector 3 (make-vector 3 '?)))
(define (display-scoreboard)
(display (vector-ref scoreboard 0))
(newline)
(display (vector-ref scoreboard 1))
(newline)
(display (vector-ref scoreboard 2))
(newline))

(define (X! pos)
(cond
((>= 3 pos) (vector-set! (vector-ref scoreboard 0) (- pos 1) 'X))
))

(display-scoreboard)
(X! 1)
(newline)
(display-scoreboard)
```

output:

```
#(? ? ?)
#(? ? ?)
#(? ? ?)

#(X ? ?)
#(X ? ?)
#(X ? ?)
```

Desired output:

```
#(? ? ?)
#(? ? ?)
#(? ? ?)

#(X ? ?)
#(? ? ?)
#(? ? ?)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The image shows that `(make-vector 3 (make-vector 3 '()))` creates a vector
that has the same row (vector) in all three slots.

Instead, write `(vector (vector '() '() '()) (vector '() '() '()) (vector '() '() '()))`.
Or make a little helper function:

```
(define (make-row) (vector '() '() '()))
(vector (make-row) (make-row) (make-row))
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @soegaard's excellent answer, I want to point out that the idiomatic way to create a non-shared vector of vectors is using `build-vector`.

```
;; ignore i and j since we want all elements to be the same
> (define table (build-vector 3 (lambda (i) (build-vector 3 (lambda (j) '?)))))
> table
'#(#(? ? ?) #(? ? ?) #(? ? ?))
;; this will mutate only one row
> (vector-set! (vector-ref table 0) 0 42)
> table
'#(#(42 ? ?) #(? ? ?) #(? ? ?))
;; we can use i and j to make different elements for each index
> (build-vector 3 (lambda (i) (build-vector 3 (lambda (j) (* (add1 i) (add1 j))))))
'#(#(1 2 3) #(2 4 6) #(3 6 9))
```