# why is one call to 'vector-set!' changing several vectors in a nested vector, when given one inner vector?

Tags: scheme, racket

running the block of code below

```
#lang racket
(define nested-vector (make-vector 2 (make-vector 2 'a)))

(define inner-vector (vector-ref nested-vector 0)) 
(vector-set! inner-vector 0 'b)
(displayln nested-vector)
```

it displays:

```
#(#(b a) #(b a))
```

what I would expect it to display is:

```
#(#(b a) #(a a))
```

meaning that only the inner-vector would change.

why does vector-set! behave like this?

Comment: The answers to this question might help: [_How are these nested vectors connected?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824929/how-are-these-nested-vectors-connected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```lisp
(define vector2 (make-vector 2 'a))
(define nested-vector (make-vector 2 vector2))
```

When written this way, you should be able to see that the inner vectors are both the same vector, not two different vectors. So when you modify it, both elements of `nested-vector` are affected.

To make a vector with two distinct nested vectors, you need to call `make-vector` separately for each element.

```
(define nested-vector (vector (make-vector 2 'a) (make-vector 2 'a)))
```